# Weird IDE behaviour in visual studio 2015 - compiles but marks non existing errors

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015

I just updgraded to VS 2015 from VS 2012. In most files I open there is a weird annoying behaviour, which you'll see in the following images.

some `using`s are greyed out, and marked as "unnecessary", but not all are, because I'm using those namespaces in the code. And indeed, all classes/methods taken from those namespaces are underlined and treaten by the IDE as compilation errors, but the project compiles nonetheless!
In fact, these screenshots are taken during a debugging session.

Is there a weird VS 2015 option I haven't correctly set? Please note, I did not oversee the migration from VS2012 to VS2015, a colleague of mine did and prepare the pc for me, so I wasn't aware of everything he did, but I completely trust him :-)

[image]

`ILogger` and `DateRange` are from the `Archimede.Common` namespace, while `GetOrLoadEntities` comes from `Archimede.HRSuite.DAL`

[image]

Thank you!

Comment: have you installed the updates for VisualStudio?

Comment: It probably says that the 'using's are not necessary because it doesn't properly recognize any of the code that would use it. I got these when I installed VS the first time because it didn't properly import the References and I had to go into the References menu and find them all again.

Comment: As some of the namespaces are also marked red, I suppose that you're missing the required referenced DLL which contains the namespaces. Are you sure that all required DLLs are referenced and that these referenced DLLs are also present?

Comment: The only updates in "Extensions and Updates" are Azure SDK 2.9.5 and SQL Server Data Tools. The references are still there, noone touched them. LinuxDisciple, you're suggesting to remove them and add them back again?

Comment: In Error List Window, switch to Compile Only to avoid false alarms in IntelliSense.